Visual Studio CMake project: environment variable missing
I'm trying to create CMake Project in Visual Studio 2022 Community, but get following error:
1> [CMake] -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.39.33519/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - broken
1> [CMake] CMake Error at C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/CMake/share/cmake-3.28/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:67 (message):
1> [CMake]   The C compiler
1> [CMake] 
1> [CMake]     "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.39.33519/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe"
1> [CMake] 
1> [CMake]   is not able to compile a simple test program.
1> [CMake] 
1> [CMake]   It fails with the following output:
1> [CMake] 
1> [CMake]     Change Dir: 'C:/Users/booksword/source/repos/CMakeProject2/out/build/x64-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-wv920j'
1> [CMake]     
1> [CMake]     Run Build Command(s): "C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/Community/Common7/IDE/CommonExtensions/Microsoft/CMake/Ninja/ninja.exe" -v cmTC_ad1cb
1> [CMake]     [1/2] C:\PROGRA~1\MIB055~1\2022\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1439~1.335\bin\Hostx64\x64\cl.exe  /nologo   /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3  /MDd /Ob0 /Od /RTC1 -Zi /showIncludes /FoCMakeFiles\cmTC_ad1cb.dir\testCCompiler.c.obj /FdCMakeFiles\cmTC_ad1cb.dir\ /FS -c C:\Users\booksword\source\repos\CMakeProject2\out\build\x64-debug\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-wv920j\testCCompiler.c
1> [CMake]     [2/2] C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /C "cd . && "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E vs_link_exe --intdir=CMakeFiles\cmTC_ad1cb.dir --rc=C:\PROGRA~2\WI3CF2~1\10\bin\100203~1.0\x86\rc.exe --mt=C:\PROGRA~2\WI3CF2~1\10\bin\100203~1.0\x86\mt.exe --manifests  -- C:\PROGRA~1\MIB055~1\2022\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1439~1.335\bin\Hostx64\x64\link.exe /nologo CMakeFiles\cmTC_ad1cb.dir\testCCompiler.c.obj  /out:cmTC_ad1cb.exe /implib:cmTC_ad1cb.lib /pdb:cmTC_ad1cb.pdb /version:0.0 /machine:x64  /debug /INCREMENTAL /subsystem:console  kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib && cd ."
1> [CMake]     FAILED: cmTC_ad1cb.exe 
1> [CMake]     C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /C "cd . && "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E vs_link_exe --intdir=CMakeFiles\cmTC_ad1cb.dir --rc=C:\PROGRA~2\WI3CF2~1\10\bin\100203~1.0\x86\rc.exe --mt=C:\PROGRA~2\WI3CF2~1\10\bin\100203~1.0\x86\mt.exe --manifests  -- C:\PROGRA~1\MIB055~1\2022\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1439~1.335\bin\Hostx64\x64\link.exe /nologo CMakeFiles\cmTC_ad1cb.dir\testCCompiler.c.obj  /out:cmTC_ad1cb.exe /implib:cmTC_ad1cb.lib /pdb:cmTC_ad1cb.pdb /version:0.0 /machine:x64  /debug /INCREMENTAL /subsystem:console  kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib && cd ."
1> [CMake]     LINK Pass 1: command "C:\PROGRA~1\MIB055~1\2022\COMMUN~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1439~1.335\bin\Hostx64\x64\link.exe /nologo CMakeFiles\cmTC_ad1cb.dir\testCCompiler.c.obj /out:cmTC_ad1cb.exe /implib:cmTC_ad1cb.lib /pdb:cmTC_ad1cb.pdb /version:0.0 /machine:x64 /debug /INCREMENTAL /subsystem:console kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib /MANIFEST /MANIFESTFILE:CMakeFiles\cmTC_ad1cb.dir/intermediate.manifest CMakeFiles\cmTC_ad1cb.dir/manifest.res" failed (exit code 1104) with the following output:
1> [CMake]     LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'kernel32.lib'
1> [CMake] 
1> [CMake]     ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

This happens even if I create completely new CMake Project without any change from what Visual Studio automatically generated.
However, the same VS version installed on another laptop can build without any problem.
I then compared the output of the two computers, and I found that on the problematic computer the environment variable printed out is
1> Environment settings:
1>     OneDriveConsumer=J:\OneDrive
1>     ProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)
1>     CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER=(base)
1>     windir=C:\WINDOWS
1>     PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=AMD64 Family 23 Model 113 Stepping 0, AuthenticAMD
1>     RA3_NEW_WB_DIR=E:\Game\Red Alert 3\CoronaResources\NewWorldBuilder
1>     VBOX_MSI_INSTALL_PATH=E:\Applications\Oracle\VirtualBox\
1>     TMP=C:\Users\BOOKSW~1\AppData\Local\Temp
1>     PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=AMD64
1>     BOOST_ROOT=E:\Applications\boost
1>     Path=C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v12.1\bin;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v12.1\libnvvp;E:\Applications\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pywin32_system32;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.8\bin;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.8\libnvvp;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin;E:\Applications\anaconda3;E:\Applications\anaconda3\Scripts;E:\Applications\anaconda3\Library\bin;E:\Applications\anaconda3\Library\mingw-w64\bin;E:\Applications\anaconda3\condabin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;E:\MediaTools\ffmpeg\bin;E:\Applications\MATLAB\R2021b\runtime\win64;E:\Applications\MATLAB\R2021b\bin;E:\Applications\texlive\bin\win32;C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\WolframScript\;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;E:\Applications\nvm;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;E:\Applications\Android\SDK\platform-tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\CUDNN\v8.6.0\bin;E:\Applications\protoc\bin;C:\Strawberry\c\bin;C:\Strawberry\perl\site\bin;C:\Strawberry\perl\bin;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\Nsight Compute 2023.1.1\;C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLIV2\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.39.33519\bin\Hostx64\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.20348.0\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Incredibuild;C:\Users\booksword\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2022.2\bin;C:\Users\booksword\AppData\Local\nvs\;C:\Users\booksword\AppData\Roaming\npm;E:\Applications\nvm;C:\Program Files\nodejs;E:\Applications\smartmontools\bin;E:\Applications\texlive\bin\windows;C:\Users\booksword\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;E:\Applications\kdbplus\w64;
1>     HF_HOME=E:\huggingface
1>     PkgDefApplicationConfigFile=C:\Users\booksword\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\17.0_31026736\devenv.exe.config
1>     USERPROFILE=C:\Users\booksword
1>     CONDA_SHLVL=1
1>     PROCESSOR_REVISION=7100
1>     ServiceHubLogSessionKey=D4D1C6D8
1>     FPS_BROWSER_APP_PROFILE_STRING=Internet Explorer
1>     FPS_BROWSER_USER_PROFILE_STRING=Default
1>     LOGONSERVER=\\DESKTOP-MSRCVT0
1>     TEMP=C:\Users\BOOKSW~1\AppData\Local\Temp
1>     USERNAME=booksword
1>     CUDA_PATH_V12_1=C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v12.1
1>     RA3_Root_Dir=E:\Game\Red Alert 3\
1>     CONDA_EXE=E:\Applications\anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe
1>     QHOME=E:\Applications\kdbplus
1>     QLIC=E:\Applications\kdbplus
1>     OneDrive=J:\OneDrive
1>     USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE=DESKTOP-MSRCVT0
1>     NVTOOLSEXT_PATH=C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NvToolsExt\
1>     CommonProgramFiles=C:\Program Files\Common Files
1>     VisualStudioDir=D:\Documents\Visual Studio 2022
1>     ProgramW6432=C:\Program Files
1>     ProgramData=C:\ProgramData
1>     VS_Perf_Session_GCHeapCount=2
1>     VSAPPIDDIR=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\
1>     HOMEPATH=\Users\booksword
1>     PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
1>     COMPUTERNAME=DESKTOP-MSRCVT0
1>     VSSKUEDITION=Community
1>     ALLUSERSPROFILE=C:\ProgramData
1>     CommonProgramW6432=C:\Program Files\Common Files
1>     VsPerMonitorDpiAwarenessEnabled.39624=TRUE
1>     ThreadedWaitDialogDpiContext=-4
1>     CONDA_PYTHON_EXE=E:\Applications\anaconda3\python.exe
1>     NVM_HOME=E:\Applications\nvm
1>     GCExpConfigUsedInSession=3
1>     SignInWithHomeTenantOnly=False
1>     SESSIONNAME=Console
1>     CUDA_PATH=C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v12.1
1>     DriverData=C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\DriverData
1>     HOMEDRIVE=C:
1>     CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV=base
1>     SystemRoot=C:\WINDOWS
1>     CONDA_PREFIX=E:\Applications\anaconda3
1>     SystemDrive=C:
1>     NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS=24
1>     OS=Windows_NT
1>     ProgramFiles=C:\Program Files
1>     EFC_5000=1
1>     VSLANG=1033
1>     PSModulePath=C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules;C:\Program Files\Intel\Wired Networking\
1>     NVM_SYMLINK=C:\Program Files\nodejs
1>     APPDATA=C:\Users\booksword\AppData\Roaming
1>     USERDOMAIN=DESKTOP-MSRCVT0
1>     PROCESSOR_LEVEL=23
1>     LOCALAPPDATA=C:\Users\booksword\AppData\Local
1>     VisualStudioVersion=17.0
1>     PyCharm=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2022.2\bin;
1>     VisualStudioEdition=Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022
1>     CommonProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
1>     CUDA_PATH_V11_8=C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.8
1>     PUBLIC=C:\Users\Public
1>     VSAPPIDNAME=devenv.exe
1>     MSBuildLoadMicrosoftTargetsReadOnly=true

In which there is no environment variables such as "INCLUDE", "LIBS". But on my succeeded laptop these environment variables exists and points to the current Windows SDK folder.
So the issue should be here. However, I cannot find where these environment variables get set in Visual Studio IDE. On both side I didn't set them as system or user environment variables in outsize VS IDE.
So my question is, where does the VS IDE (or the CMake embedded) set its own environment variables other than the system-level ones?
Can someone kindly help please? Thanks a lot!

Tried to clear the project folder, no luck;
Tried to repair VS, no luck;
Tried to uninstall and then reinstall VS, no luck.

